# Google translate is not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

It started to be happened for some days. I could not click on any tabs on the translation windows.

My OS is Windows 10, I'm using Google Chrome - Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image: google translate is not working]

Comment: Try to delete cookies and caches on Chrome.

Comment: it works again, thank.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deleting cookies and emptying the cache constitute the usual remedy in such situations. To get targeted advice and contribute with possible improvements to the Google Translate product, you may consider [joining the translate community](https://translate.google.com/community?source=t-new-user).